# React-native-android build error:Could not find implementation 'com.facebook.react.ReactRootProjectPlugin' for plugin 'com.facebook.react.rootproject'

Tags: react-native, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been trying to build my first android app using
`npx react-native run-android`
i have been getting the error
I tried manipulating my build.graddle file in android folder etc etc nothing worked
can you help me figure this out please?[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osh1b.png)

i tried ./gradlew clean
i tried manipulating my build.graddle with adding react-native version
i tried changing settings.graddle package
nothing worked, each of them created new errors again.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm i
cd android
./gradlew clean
npx react-native run-android
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please add details to this list of commands, it would be helpful for OP and other people who would see your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).